# CartThrob will be ported to EE4

Tags: cartthrob, ee4-upgrade

Cartthrob is a fantastic cart framework!

at first I thought it was complex to use, but with the help of excellent documentation.

I'm wondering if CartThrob will be ported to EE4. Or if CartThrob 3 is compatible with EE4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The EE3 version of CartThrob is not compatible with EE4.

Development of an EE4 version of CartThrob is [apparently underway](https://twitter.com/CartThrob/status/948897457034944512), but it not yet available.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, and very happy to know CartThrob is on the list of ExpressionEngine 4 update.